# While loop iteration in CSS selector for List value

Tags: javascript, css, loops, while-loop

In the below content, I want to iterate the value available in "month" variable in the while loop.
    While I am trying, it shows info as "Expecting integer value".

```
if (selectedForYear() == 2016) {
   var d = new Date();
   var month = d.getMonth();
   while (month <= 11) {
     $('.accordionContent .flexContent .dk_options li:nth-child(month)').css({
       "display": 'none'
     });
     n++;
   }
}
```

Is there any way to iterate month value in while loop for the css "li:nth-child(month)".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here `('.accordionContent .flexContent .dk_options li:nth-child(month)')`, month is not pointing to variable `month` but is treated as string `month`, try this `('.accordionContent .flexContent .dk_options li:nth-child('+month+')')`

Comment: @Rajesh It wont works. While I trying like above, then I cannot able to choose that particular value "2016" in dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two errors:

`month` must not be within the string literal `…nth-child(month)`. Also, you probably want to increment `month`, not `n`.

```
while (month <= 11) {
  $('.accordionContent .flexContent .dk_options li:nth-child(' + month + ')').css({ "display": 'none' });
  month ++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `parseInt()`, what was missing is the concatenation with the variable. You need to concatenate the variable's value with the selector

```
$('.accordionContent .flexContent .dk_options li:nth-child('+ parseInt(month)+')').css({ "display": 'none' });
```

Comment: It wont works. While I trying like above, then I cannot able to choose that particular value "2016" in dropdown in the UI.